# gitconfigのプロキシ設定をワイルドカードでまとめて行いたい

Tags: git, proxy

Windows serverでGit for Windowsを使っています。
特定のリポジトリのアクセスだけプロキシサーバを使う設定にしたいです。

[gitのproxy設定をリポジトリごとに変える方法](https://qiita.com/emudome/items/2e7942104d66d59fd577)

を参照しましたが、同じようなURLを1つ1つ設定するのは大変なので、
`https://*.example.com/*`
のようなワイルドカードでの設定はできないのでしょうか？

Comment: 「拝見」は謙譲語で、見せた相手、つまり筆者を敬う語です。筆者に向けられていない場面においては誤用だと思います。

Comment: ドメインには所有者がおり、正当な所有者でないならば無断使用すべきではありません。質問の際は`example.com`など例示用ドメインを使いましょう。

Comment: ご教示頂きありがとうございます。さまざまなご指摘ありがとうございます。ワイルカード試行しましたが、適応されないようで、接続エラーになりました。

Comment: 「プロキシの例外設定」という表現だと一般的には「常にプロキシを使うけど、特定のアクセス時のみ無効にする」というイメージが強いですが、質問本文を読むと「特定のリポジトリのみにプロキシを反映したい」ようで、タイトルと本文を念のため見直してもらった方が良さそうです。

Comment: 「接続エラーになりました」だけでは情報量がありません。確認ですが、ワイルドカードを使わなければエラーにならないのですか？

Comment: リポジトリの完全なURLは`https://abc.example.com/test.git`です。これで設定すると接続できますが、`https://*.example.com/test.git`では接続エラーになります。

Comment: どう設定したら接続できて、どう設定したら接続できないのか、概念でなく具体的な設定値を質問文に記載してください。

Answer (score 3):

[`git-config` の `http.<url>.*` の項](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httplturlgt)（リンクが壊れていて該当箇所には飛べないようです）に

> `https://*.example.com/` for example would match `https://foo.example.com/`, but not `https://foo.bar.example.com/`.

とありました。

```
[http]
    proxy = http://proxy.acme.com:8080

[http "http://*.example.com/"]
    proxy =
```

であれば書けるようです。